# Can a self-complementary graph on 100 vertices have precisely one vertex of degree 50?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I suspect the answer is no, but I can't seem to prove it. If $v\in G$ has $\deg_{G}(v)=50$, then $\deg_{\overline G}(v)=49$, so the vertex of degree 50 taking $v$'s role in $\overline G$ is a different vertex, say $u$.

Now I think I should study the relationship between $u$ and $v$, maybe ask whether they're neighbours or not, but I'm not managing to conclude that there must be other vertices with degree 50.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a (finite) self-complementary graph, and let $f$ be an anti-automorphism of $G$, i.e., an isomorphism $f:G\to\overline G$, where $\overline G$ is the complement of $G$. Viewed as a permutation of $V$, $f$ has at most one fixed point and, aside from that, each cycle in its disjoint cycle representation has length divisible by $4$; this follows from the fact that the induced permutation of $E$ has only cycles of even length. This is one way of showing that the order of a self-complementary graph is of the form $4n$ or $4n+1$.

Now suppose $G$ has order $4n$, so that the anti-automorphism $f$ contains only cycles of length divisible by $4$. Then the permutation $f^2$, which is an automorphism of $G$, contains only cycles of even length. This proves that a self-complementary graph of order $4n$ contains an even number of vertices of degree $d$. Similarly, a self-complementary graph of order $4n+1$ contains an even number of vertices of degree $d$, provided $d\ne2n$.